Bulk copy do not execute when called SSIS package called from Autosys
I have Ssis package deployed on integration service catalog.
It execute perfectly when I right click and execute the package on SSIS db.
However when the package is triggered from autosys it does all the step except the bulk copy .
The bulk copy does nothing when package is called from autosys.
Changing the database works fine with autosys job too .

Autosys service account didn't have the bulk insert permission.
It got resolved by
GRANT ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK
